# merge two sorted linked list into one linked list (recursion)

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I had to write a recursive function that receives two sorted lists:

```
typedef struct listNode {
    int* dataPtr;
    struct listNode* next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct list
{
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;
} List;
```

and merge them into one sorted list.

I wrote these functions:

```
void mergeRec(ListNode* head1, ListNode* head2, ListNode* mergedList)
{
    if (head1 == NULL && head2 == NULL)
        return;
    else if (head1 == NULL) {
        mergedList->next = head2;
        head2 = head2->next;
    }
    else if (head2 == NULL) {
        mergedList->next = head1;
        head1 = head1->next;
    }
    else if (*(head1->dataPtr) > *(head2->dataPtr)) {
        mergedList->next = head1;
        head1 = head1->next;
    }
    else
    {
        mergedList->next = head2;
        head2 = head2->next;
    }

    mergeRec(head1, head2, mergedList->next);
}

List merge(List lst1, List lst2)
{
    List mergedList;
    makeEmptyList(&mergedList);
    mergeRec(lst1.head, lst2.head, mergedList.head);
    return mergedList;
}
```

Now, the problem I have with the recursive function is that at the first call when merged list is pointing to null, so obviously when I write something like `mergeList->next` I will get a running bug.

I tried to solve it by adding the following condition in the recursion:

```
    if (mergedList == NULL)
    {
        if (*(head1->dataPtr) > *(head2->dataPtr))
        {
            mergedList = head1;
            head1 = head1->next;
        }
        else
        {
            mergedList = head2;
            head2 = head2->next;
        }
    }
```

but I got this error:

> "Exception thrown at 0x00661EB9 in q2d.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01000F48."

I can't tell the problem, or how do I solve it.
I would very much appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does this data  int* dataPtr; have the pointer type instead of just int data;?!

Comment: Please note that in C all the arguments of a function are passed by *value*, even pointers, so that with `mergedList = head1;` you are changing the local copy, not the pointer you passed.

Comment: Add a recursion termination of `if (!head1) return head2; else if (!head2) return head1;` before you compare and recurse to merge.

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is entirely unclear why in this structure there is a data member of type `int *`

```
typedef struct listNode {
    int* dataPtr;
    struct listNode* next;
}List;
```

instead of just of type `int`

```
typedef struct listNode {
    int data;
    struct listNode* next;
}List;
```

Nevertheless, the functions `merge` and `mergeRec` are invalid because they deal with copies of values of lists and of pointers  list1.head, list2.head, and mergedList.head.

```
List merge(List lst1, List lst2)
mergeRec(lst1.head, lst2.head, mergedList.head);
```

Moreover the pointers list1.tail, list2.tail, and mergedList.tail are ignored.

I can suggest the following solution shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct listNode 
{
    int *dataPtr;
    struct listNode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct list
{
    ListNode *head;
    ListNode *tail;
} List;

void makeEmpty( List *list )
{
    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
}

int push( List *list, int data )
{
    ListNode *current = malloc( sizeof( ListNode ) );
    int success = current != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        current->dataPtr = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
        success = current->dataPtr != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            *current->dataPtr = data;
            current->next = NULL;

            if ( list->head == NULL )
            {
                list->head = list->tail = current;
            }
            else
            {
                list->tail = list->tail->next = current;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            free( current );
            current = NULL;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

List merge( List *first, List *second )
{
    List result;
    makeEmpty( &result );

    if ( ( second->head != NULL ) && 
         ( first->head == NULL || *second->head->dataPtr < *first->head->dataPtr ) )
    {
        result.head = result.tail = second->head;
        second->head = second->head->next;
        if ( second->head == NULL ) second->tail = NULL;
    }
    else if ( first->head != NULL )
    {
        result.head = result.tail = first->head;
        first->head = first->head->next;
        if ( first->head == NULL ) first->tail = NULL;
    }

    if ( !( first->head == NULL && second->head == NULL ) )
    {
        List tmp = merge( first, second );
        result.head->next = tmp.head;
        result.tail = tmp.tail;
    }

    return result;
}

void output( const List *list )
{
    for ( const ListNode *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *current->dataPtr );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    List even_numbers;
    List odd_numbers;

    makeEmpty( &even_numbers );
    makeEmpty( &odd_numbers );

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        i % 2 == 0 ? push( &even_numbers, i )
                   : push( &odd_numbers, i );
    }

    printf( "even_numbers: " ); output( &even_numbers );
    printf( "odd_numbers:  " ); output( &odd_numbers );

    List all_numbers = merge( &even_numbers, &odd_numbers );

    printf( "all_numbers:  " ); output( &all_numbers );
    printf( "even_numbers: " ); output( &even_numbers );
    printf( "odd_numbers:  " ); output( &odd_numbers );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
even_numbers: 0 2 4 6 8 NULL
odd_numbers:  1 3 5 7 9 NULL
all_numbers:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 NULL
even_numbers: NULL
odd_numbers:  NULL
```